# Excel #value is correct but still shows #value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing a financial statement, and I have circular reference. When I change an option in a cell(1 or 2) every other cell changes. Some cells changes to #value, but when i click on that cell and manually click enter again it shows up the correct value. How do I get rid of the #value? Only way I can get rid of it is manually clicking the formula and clicking enter again,but I dont want to do that every time I change the options. Thanks in advance.

If anyone's confused, here's a simple example.

A1 is either 1 or 2(combo box)

B2 = A1 + 1

C2 = B2 + 1

D2 = C2 + 1

So if A1 I manually put is 1, then B2 will be 2, C2 will be 3, D2 will be 4.

Now when manually change A1 to 2, B2 will be 2, C2 will show up as #value, and D2 will show up as #value. If i click on D2 and click enter again, nothing happens, but if I click C2 and click enter, C2 shows up correctly(3), and D2 changes to 4. How do I get rid of #value?

Comment: You should go to the target of the problem (wherever the error is) and "Show Calculation Steps..." to hopefully trace the source of the problem. It's no use trying to remedy it with your approach; one should rather set conditionals so that your output can accommodate all possible input (within reason).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but do you know why this happens? Technically it shouldn't happen, because everything is linked correctly. I don't even know where the issue starts :( I'm pretty sure I had conditions on it. I'm using a combo box, so the input 1,2 is linked to that.

Comment: Are you sure that's a combo box and not a data validation?

Comment: @user3784616: You mention in your post that you have "[you have a] circular reference". Is this true?

Comment: Just a (probably wrong) suggestion, but have you tried recalculating *just* that sheet with a `Shift-F9`? I'm not saying it'll work, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: It is a combo box, not data validation. Also not A circular reference(more like 200 of them lol)

Comment: You can try FormulaDesk http://www.formuladesk.com It can display a decomposed view of your formula (ie: rolled-up), with each nested rolled-up expression displaying it's result. It should also help you to pinpoint where your error is. [Disclosure: FormulaDesk is my (free) product]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your excel file itself is an export or something like that.

Try to open a new excel file.

Do exactly what you did in this excel file.

See if the error is still there.

It happens a lot when you work out of export files or other sort of excel files.

You can maybe solve it in your current file, bu using "Text to Column" (in the data tab)
Select the whole column where you have your forumula in

Select "text to columns" in the data tab

Press finish right away

Then save the file as a different kind of excel file.

But it's better to copy paste (formulas) to a new excel file. Dont copy the formats with it.